# scraping pagination with Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, pagination

I am new in Python and also in Web scraping...

I am trying to select all the pages from this webpage

http://www.pour-les-personnes-agees.gouv.fr/annuaire-ehpad-en-hebergement-permanent/64/0

this is quite complicated: I saw the html code with "active first" and "next last.

I did a python code and it worked for 4 pages (page 2,3,4 and 11)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url_pagination= "http://www.pour-les-personnes-agees.gouv.fr/annuaire-ehpad-en-hebergement-permanent/64/0"
dept_page_Url=[]
r=requests.get(url_pagination)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
pagination= soup.find_all("ul",{"class":"pagination"})
if len(pagination) == 0 :
    dept_page_Url.append(url_pagination)
else:
    for page_url_list in pagination:
        for page_url in page_url_list.find_all("a"):
            dept_page_Url.append(root_url + page_url.get('href'))
print(dept_page_Url)
```

In fact I know why I have just 4 pages, it is because I selected only the "Href" html code. But I don't know how to improve my code.

Any clue such as a webpage with some information to help me or some who know how to do it???

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pagination gives only 4 links (pages 2-4 and the last page), so you can't get all the page links from the html document directly.
However you can get the number of pages from the last page and create all the pages with `range`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_pagination= "http://www.pour-les-personnes-agees.gouv.fr/annuaire-ehpad-en-hebergement-permanent/64/0"
r = requests.get(url_pagination)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

page_url = "http://www.pour-les-personnes-agees.gouv.fr/annuaire-ehpad-en-hebergement-permanent/64/0?page={}"
last_page = soup.find('ul', class_='pagination').find('li', class_='next').a['href'].split('=')[1]
#last_page = soup.select_one('ul.pagination li.next a')['href'].split('=')[1] # with css selectors
dept_page_url = [page_url.format(i) for i in range(1, int(last_page)+1)]

print(dept_page_url)
```

---

`soup.find('ul', class_='pagination').find('li', class_='next').a['href']` finds the first 'ul.pagination', then 'li.next', then 'a', and selects 'href'.
The result is: '/annuaire-ehpad-en-hebergement-permanent/64/0?page=11'.

[`.split('=')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) splits the string by '=' in a list of 2 items and `.split('=')[1]` selects the 2nd item which is '11', so `last_page = '11'`.

`range(1, int(last_page)+1)` creates a range of numbers from 1 to 11.

[`page_url.format(i)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) formats those numbers in `page_url`, so `dept_page_url` contains 11 urls.

Comment: Thank you very much, It works very well. I am trying to understand your code and I have some difficulty to find in the last page the class "next ".. but thanks a lot

Comment: I've added explanatory notes, but if you have any questions feel free to ask.